# Excel - Bar chart - years in y-axis and variables in x-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I'm trying to chart the following:

- I want a bar showing the **total** fruit
- I want the fruit in the Y-axis
- The years in the X-axis - so you can visually see the impact per year of each category.

Hope that makes sense...

```
        2018    2019    2020    2021    Total
Apples  1       4       5       1       11
Pears   2       5       6       1       14
Banana  4       6       4       6       20
Peach   5       5       2       5       17
Grapes  6       8       3       2       19
```

Many thanks

Comment: You describe 2 different things to be shown on the y axis and nothing else, please clarify your question. Desired output (even a hand-drawn picture) could be useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: I assume you want the years on the x-axis and the fruit-total on the y-axis, right? What did you try so far to solve your problem? @Tetsujin I would give him the chance to explain before closing the question just after 5 min!

Comment: Sorry - new to this....

Comment: Yes that's right Albin  I'm trying to show how much is completed by each yearly interval - in comparison to the total

Comment: Next time you should also edit your question in addition to write an answer in the comments. (I did it for you this time)

Comment: Have you tried doing it?  Excel has a built in wizard to create charts for you.  Hint: you may need to tell Excel whether the series are in rows or columns.

Comment: @fixer1234 is there a different "char wizard" then the one I describe in my answer?

Comment: I’m not unfamiliar with excel chats. It’s just that I was asked to produce something that really didn’t make sense, but the manager thought it was possible. After several discussions I was able to show him how it couldn’t be done, you can’t have a year on the y axis and 2 differing points on the x axis (where he wanted to represent the fruits). Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to add a row below your last row with the total fruits per year. Then just select the row and choose to add a chart from the menu. THis way excel will create the desired chart for you. Like this:

[image].

If you want to add the years to to the chart instead of 1,2,3... right click the chart, select "choose data", click on the edit button for the horizontal data an select the row with the titles as shown in this screen shot:

[image]

Additionally I would suggest, if you don't necessarily need it "your way", to put the fruits on the X-axis and the years on the Y-axis. The "running" data stream (in your case the years), should technically go from top to bottom in a table. In general this will work better with the automated excel features.